# Creating a label array-Trying it but whats wrong?

Tags: c#, arrays, label

this is the code:

```
        Label[] labelxx = new Label[5];
        this.Controls.Add(labelxx[0]);
        labelxx[0] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        labelxx[0].Text = "stuff";
        labelxx[0].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 250);
        labelxx[0].ForeColor = Color.White;
        labelxx[0].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        labelxx[0].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 35);
```

as you can see, I have set pretty much everything... text, location, size, forecolor-backcolor(to make it more visible in case I cant see it)
However this not working... whats wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
    Label[] labelxx = new Label[5];

    labelxx[0] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    labelxx[0].Text = "stuff";
    labelxx[0].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 250);
    labelxx[0].ForeColor = Color.White;
    labelxx[0].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    labelxx[0].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 35);

    this.Controls.Add(labelxx[0]);
```

Comment: this worked -- But I dont get it, why we add control after we done everything, not after we created the array ? (I will mark this best after about 11 minute)

Comment: you must create the object before add it to the control list.

Comment: @Foresp - New arrays of anything are initialized to Nulls. labelxx[0] = new... changes the Null to a ref to a label. You could do the 'controls.add' right after that line and all would work OK.

Comment: @Foresp. When you created the array, because it's an array of a class (Label in this case) all elements will be null initially, which is whatyou added to the form. Honestly i'm surprised it let you add a null!.

Comment: @Foresp - re Jairo's comment - this applies to all objects/lists - think about the reference in the value, it is a memory address of the recently new'd item. You'll trip over value vs. reference types, and objects in general, if you don't eventually get it. Believe it or not the Garbage Collector also has a pointer back to every object reference (here the array elements) - it needs to so it can move the objects!!  (change the array references) Apologies if you already knew all this... Another easy confusing thing is that arrays of reference types (e.g., object ref's) aren't pointed to new objs

Comment: **You forgot to explain *why* this works.** Posting magic code isn't helping anyone. -1

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really added the label to the form. When you create an array of labels, all the elements in it will be initialized to `null`. And then when you add one of those elements to the form, you're just adding `null`. You need to add the label to the form only after you created it.

```
    Label[] labelxx = new Label[5];
    labelxx[0] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    labelxx[0].... // blah blah set everything
    this.Controls.Add(labelxx[0]);
```